# Multiple Feign clients with different interceptors

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

I have two Feign clients *in Spring Boot* doing different things, but would like them to be authenticated differently.

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "...",
    url = "${url1}",
    configuration = Config1.class
)
public interface Client1 {
    @PostMapping(
        path = "...",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    JsonNode doThing(@RequestBody JsonNode thing);
}

@FeignClient(
    name = "...",
    url = "${url2}",
    configuration = Config2.class
)
public interface Client2 {
    @PostMapping(
        path = "...",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    JsonNode doThing(@RequestBody JsonNode thing);
}
```

They both need basic authentication, but different values for username and password. For that, I thought about having separate `Config` classes to set their respective clients:

```
@Configuration
public class Client1 {
    private final String user;
    private final String password;

    public Client1(final Config1 config) {
        this.user = config.getUser();
        this.password = config.getPassword();
    }

    @Bean(name = "client1")
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(user, password);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class Client2 {
    private final String user;
    private final String password;

    public Client1(final Config2 config) {
        this.user = config.getUser();
        this.password = config.getPassword();
    }

    @Bean(name = "client2")
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(user, password);
    }
}
```

But my API is returning HTTP 4xx errors, as if the interceptor did not work at all. Can I get some pointers on setting this up properly?

(Notice that I gave those beans `name`s, because they will otherwise conflict for DI.)

Answer (score 4):

I guess You have to remove the stereotype `@Configuration`.

I actually came here during a search to a similar problem. I do have (same like You) two different configs. One FeignClient with and a second client without auth. But the second client is using both RequestInterceptors (I implemented a noop-RequestInterceptor just for logging).

Could You actually solve your problem?

Comment: I am having the same problem.... did somebody resolve it?

Comment: Check, that there is no Spring Boot Annotation like `@Configuration` on your config classes.

Comment: It works for me. Cause one feign client used wrong RequestInterceptor (I guess spring proxy machine picked up wrong class from beans)

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `@Configuration` annotation, and use `ApplicationContext` to read configed properties:

```java
// config
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.auth.BasicAuthRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
public class Client1 {

    @Bean(name = "amapRequestInterceptor")
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        String user = SpringUtils.getProperty("client1.user", String.class, null);
        String password = SpringUtils.getProperty("client1.password", String.class, null);
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(user, password);
    }
}
// SpringUtils
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(@NonNull ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        if (SpringUtils.applicationContext == null) {
            SpringUtils.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }
    }

    public static <T> T getProperty(String key, Class<T> targetType, T defaultValue) {
        return applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty(key, targetType, defaultValue);
    }

}
```

The problem in your code is feign will use all of `RequestInterceptor` in application context so that `Authorization` header is overwrite twice.

With `@Configuration` removed, there is no RequestInterceptor in application context, feign will use `RequestInterceptor` specified by `@FeignClient`.